# WiringPi shiftOut with HCF4094 shift register

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

I have problems getting the raspi/wiringPi to work with a [HCF4094 shift register](http://www.bsselektronika.hu/pdf/ic_digit/4094.pdf).

I am using the following code part:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringShift.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int LEDClockPin  = 5;
int LEDDataPin   = 3;
int LEDStrobePin = 4;

void setup()
{
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode(LEDClockPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LEDDataPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LEDStrobePin, OUTPUT);
}

void writeLEDs(uint8_t value) {
    printf("%#8x\n", value);
    std::string s;
    shiftOut(LEDDataPin, LEDClockPin, MSBFIRST, value);
    digitalWrite(LEDStrobePin,HIGH);
    delay(2);
    digitalWrite(LEDStrobePin,LOW);
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setup();
    writeLEDs((1<<0));
    writeLEDs((1<<1));
    writeLEDs((1<<2));
    writeLEDs((1<<3));
    writeLEDs((1<<4));
    writeLEDs((1<<5));
    writeLEDs((1<<6));
}
```

and I have connected VDD + OE (Output Enable) on +5V, VSS on GND, and Strobe, Data and Clock to the according pins on the Pi.

Here are the pins that are high after each press of [enter]:

```
value - expected pins - real pins
1     - Q1            - Q1
2     - Q2            - Q2
4     - Q3            - Q2, Q6
8     - Q4            - Q4
16    - Q5            - Q6, Q7
32    - Q6            - Q7
64    - Q7            - Q7
```

And I really don't get what I am doing wrong ... Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding another `delay(2);` after `digitalWrite(LEDStrobePin,LOW);`. The reason you might need that is you are calling that function consecutively.

Comment: @Janka: You just made my day :) That really did the trick, but I really don't know why ... If you post your comment as answer, I am happy to accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unroll your calls, then it's

```
[...]
digitalWrite(LEDStrobePin,HIGH);
delay(2);
digitalWrite(LEDStrobePin,LOW);
[...]
digitalWrite(LEDStrobePin,HIGH);
delay(2);
digitalWrite(LEDStrobePin,LOW);
[...]
digitalWrite(LEDStrobePin,HIGH);
delay(2);
digitalWrite(LEDStrobePin,LOW);
```

If you don't put a `delay(2);` after `digitalWrite(LEDStrobePin,LOW);`, the switch from high to low back to high may be too short for the 4094 to notice. That depends on the stray capacitance of your layout.